# Capturing the Last Value inside Javascript

Tags: javascript, charts, plot, flotr

I am extremely sorry for the meaningless header for this Thread .

I have a question (So the reason i posted this :) )

```
    xaxis: {noTicks: 8, tickFormatter: function(n)
    {
    alert(n);
    }
```

Hi , the above function is from the charting API (Flotr API)
As per the above code , the alert gets displayed 8 times (Because noofticks/labels is 8)

Is it possible to capture the last alert (That is when n is 8 ) where 8 is the noofTicks Value .

All this i need is basically to make the last value of an array to show on X axis .

Please advice .

Comment: Why not just check whether `if (n == 8)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
xaxis: {
         noTicks: 8, 
         tickFormatter: function(n){
           if (n === 8) {alert(n);}
         }
       }
```

Now `xasis.tickFormatter(xasis.noTicks)` should do it.

Comment: Thank you very much , if i put up alerts for n , its displaying 0 200 400 600 800 1000 1200 1400 , so the value n==8 is never captured

Comment: Then we have to see more of your scripting to determine how you actually use this. I think noTicks is the length of some kind of array, and the array values are used as input for the tickFormatter method, right? If so, the last index of an array with length 8 would b 7 (arrays are zero based).